# Same font family on two websites displaying text differently

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I am using same font family on these two websites but on front end text is displaying differently.
https://www.havredegracecosmeticdentist.com/ 
http://mozibici.com/

I am using same font family, font weight, font size and spacing but nothing is working for me. Any help regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: on which text exactly?

Comment: I am using same font family throughout these two websites. I am using font-family:Muli, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;

Comment: May be I have an insecure link for mozibici.com and this can be the reason for this issue.

Comment: hello @wpdd, as I've checked your 2 websites, I think the cdns that you're using for both website with the font family is different. I tried to do some tweaks with the inspect elements and I'm sure there's an anomaly with the source of fonts. Try to download fonts and upload it on your website or try to make sure to paste the same url of font cdn :)

Comment: Yes you are right as the font family was not loading for the second website. I am working on this now. Thank you for your answer and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your font-family definitions are the same, but you load different fonts from google in the  tags.
So Muli font is available in https://www.havredegracecosmeticdentist.com/ but is not available in http://mozibici.com/.

Muli font is not availbale for http://mozibici.com/ website. Due to fallback mechanism in font-family definition the browser chooses the next existing font which is Helvetica for website http://mozibici.com/ whereas it shows Muli font for https://www.havredegracecosmeticdentist.com/ website.

And also you have font-weight 700 and font-weight 800 defined for your websites.

I made copy paste  meta tag responsible of font loading, changed the font weight and it appears similar for both websites.

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: I also figured out this but thank you for your answer and time. I accepted your answer as it seems perfect with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I have just considered the two sites above and found out that they are using different fonts now.

In the first site, the font 'Muli' is selected.
And in the second site, the font 'Helvetica' is selected.

I think, the second site hasn't the font 'Muli'. 
Please check my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right as the font was not loading for second site. I am working on this. I up voted your answer. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the link in the head for the font on the http://mozibici.com/ website, like you did in the other one.

try adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli%3A200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2Cregular%2Citalic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CFira+Sans%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2Cregular%2Citalic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext">` into the head block of the second website.

Comment: Also make sure the font-weight is the also the same as the elements on the other website, that could also affect the result (for example if you select 700 but do not include that in the google font import)

Comment: Actually the font was not loading for the second site and that is why these were displaying differently.